# Multiplying a number using a for loop at each i value

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and am following freecodecamp. As I understand, I think I should be able to multiply a number by i each time it changes in a for loop by the value of i itself. I am doing this because I am trying to factorialize. I sort of peeped at the answer and they used a factorialize type javascript function or something. I'd still like to solve this using my own coding. How would I do this?

Below is the code of what I have already tried.

```
function factorialize(num) {
  for (let i = 1; i < num; i++) {
   let answer = i * num;
  }
  return answer;
}
```

If I input 10 for a number I'd like it to take the factorial of 10 (i.e 10 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1). I would hope this to work for 0 as well somehow, but we can always start with my original question.

Comment: Declare `answer` **outside** the loop.

Comment: Ah. Care to explain why it needs to be declared outside instead of inside the loop? I'm very new to all of this. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: The `let` statement works differently than `var`. In your code the variable is essentially "private" to the loop code block, so invisible outside there.

Comment: Could I have used var inside the for loop to get the desired factorializing effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use a `while` loop too:

```js
function factorialize(num)
{
    let answer = 1;

    while (num > 0)
    {
       answer = answer * num;
       num--;
    }

    return answer;
}

console.log("Result for 0:", factorialize(0));
console.log("Result for 5:", factorialize(5));
console.log("Result for 10:", factorialize(10));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Or go the recursive way:

```js
const factorialize = (num) => num <= 0 ? 1 : num * factorialize(num - 1);

console.log("Result for 0:", factorialize(0));
console.log("Result for 5:", factorialize(5));
console.log("Result for 10:", factorialize(10));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: I really like the recursive solution because it seems to be short and sweet, especially with the ternary operator. Care to explain why the else return "num * factorialize(num - 1);" would actually return a factorial of num?

Comment: @Oversought what is `5 * 4!`? It's `5!`.

Comment: Oh so calling the function back at the end of the ternary inside the function itself is why it keeps repeating recursively. I was confused as to how that happened. I understand how factorials work, just didn't know exactly how that coding did that. I think I understand it better now though.

Comment: @Oversought Sure, I will try with a basic example. Suppose we call `factorialize(3)`, then we get `3 * factorialize(2)` in the first call. Now, that expression will be reduced to `3 * (2 * factorialize(1))` and so on, until we get `3 * (2 * (1 * (1 /*this is returned by factorialize(0)*/)))`. Note also, accepted answer should be that of **@Nina Scholz** since it explains your original problem. I was just trying to offer some alternatives.

Comment: I definitely appreciate alternatives. This is off-topic, but once I know all of these languages that I wish to learn (as many as possible), will I have to go back to school to get some credentials in CS/ or w/e or can I shoe my way into a career of this somehow? I've had issues with health/debt so it isn't easy to go back to school.

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare and initialize `answer` before the looping and you need to take `i` and `answer` for multiplying.

An while you have already `1` as starting value, you can start the loop from the second value. And you need the last value as well.

Worth a read: [What's the difference between using "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

```js
function factorialize(num) {
    let answer = 1;
    for (let i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
        answer = i * answer;
    }
    return answer;
}

console.log(factorialize(5));
```

A while loop approach

```js
function factorialize(num) {
    var product = 1;
    while (num) product *= num--;
    return product;
}

console.log(factorialize(5));
```

A recursive approach.

```js
function factorialize(num) {
    return num
        ? num * factorialize(num - 1)
        : 1;
}

console.log(factorialize(5));
```

Comment: You're the MVP thank you! Care to explain why this answer needs to be initialized or declared before the for loop/outside of it? Why can't I do what I did?

Comment: declaring inside with `let` makes the variable only visible inside of the block and the value can not be changed to hold the product of all values.

Comment: By the way this line of logic works really well for me naturally, but I will try to learn the others suggested below, especially the recursive one, as that is how it was solved in the solution on freecodecamp.

Comment: Makes sense Nina, thanks. What if I were to use my initial proposed solution but use var instead?

Comment: as long as the scope of the variable is outside of the loop, you could take either `let` or `var`.

Comment: In the recursive example you added, what's stopping it from taking it times 0, then -1, etc.? It doesn't look like there's something stopping that from happening.

Comment: the zero is stopping the recursion, because of the [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) nature of this value and the [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) returns `1`.